# Can I "import" the stages in a Jenkins Declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have several pipeline jobs, which are configured very similarly.
They all have  the same stages (of which there are about 10).

I am now I am thinking about moving  to the declarative pipeline (https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/09/19/blueocean-beta-declarative-pipeline-pipeline-editor/).

But I do not want  to define the ~10 stages in every pipeline. I want to define them at one place, and "import" them somehow.

Is this possible with declarative pipelines at all? I see that there are Libraries, but it does not seem like I could include the stage definition using them.

Comment: Did you fix it? I'm trying to do the same, I tried to used shared libraries, but it seems like you can't call a groocy file (in vars in the shared libary) at stage block, it must only be as a step.

Comment: [This github repo](https://github.com/ksuther/jenkins-jenkinsfile-include/blob/master/Jenkinsfile) seems to have something similar to what would be required, but it doesn't seem to work for a pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create a shared-library to implement what i am about to suggest. For shared-library implementation, you may check the following posts:

[Using Building Blocks in Jenkins Declarative Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62190395/using-building-blocks-in-jenkins-declarative-pipeline/62191503#62191503)

[Upload file in Jenkins input step to workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57464227/upload-file-in-jenkins-input-step-to-workspace/57546728#57546728) (Mainly for images so one can easily figure out things)

Now if you want to use a Jenkinsfile (kind of a *template*) which can be *reused* across *multiple* projects (jobs), then that is *indeed* possible.

Once you have created a shared-library repository with `vars` directory in it, then you just have to create a Groovy file (let's say, commonPipeline.groovy) inside `vars` directory.

Here's an example that *works* because I have used it earlier in *multiple* jobs.

---

```
$ cat shared-lib/vars/commonPipeline.groovy

// You can create function(s) as shown below, if required
def someFunctionA() {
    // Your code
}

// This is where you will define all the stages that you want
// to run as a whole in multiple projects (jobs)
def call(Map config) {
    pipeline {
        agent {
            node { label 'slaveA || slaveB' }
        }

        environment {
            myvar_Y = 'apple'
            myvar_Z = 'orange'
        }

        stages {
            stage('Checkout') {
                steps {
                    deleteDir()
                    checkout scm
                }
            }

            stage ('Build') {
                steps {
                    script {
                        check_something = someFunctionA()

                        if (check_something) {
                            echo "Build!"
                            # your_build_code
                        } else {
                            error "Something bad happened! Exiting..."
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            stage ('Test') {
                steps {
                    echo "Running tests..."
                    // your_test_code
                }
            }

            stage ('Deploy') {
                steps {
                    script {
                        sh '''
                            # your_deploy_code
                        '''
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        post {
            failure {
                sh '''
                    # anything_you_need_to_perform_in_failure_step
                ''' 
            }

            success {
                sh '''
                    # anything_you_need_to_perform_in_success_step
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With above Groovy file in place, all you have to do now is to call it in your various Jenkins projects. Since you might already be having an existing Jenkinsfile (if not, create it) in your Jenkins project, you just have to replace the existing content of that file with the following:

```
$ cat Jenkinsfile
// Assuming you have named your shared-library as `my-shared-lib` & `Default version` to `master` branch in 
// `Manage Jenkins` » `Configure System` » `Global Pipeline Libraries` section
@Library('my-shared-lib@master')_

def params = [:]

params=[
    jenkins_var: "${env.JOB_BASE_NAME}",
]

commonPipeline params
```

Note: As you can see above, I am calling `commonPipeline.groovy` file. So, all your bulky Jenkinsfile will get reduced to just five or six lines of code, and those few lines are also going to be *common* across all those projects. Also note that I have used `jenkins_var` above. It can be any name. It's not actually used but *is* required for pipeline to run. Some Groovy expert can clarify that part.

Ref: https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/10/02/pipeline-templates-with-shared-libraries/