# Fetching uploaded files in Jenkins

Tags: file, jenkins, file-upload, parameters, jenkins-pipeline

Upload (per progress bottom bar status) goes through in Jenkins. But don't see option to locate or fetch uploaded file from Jenkins.

Here is simple script with File parameters,

```
properties(
    [
        parameters(
            [ file(name: "file1.zip", description: 'Choose path to upload file1.zip from local system.'),
              file(name: "file2.zip", description: 'Choose path to upload file2.zip from local system.') ]
            )
    ]
)

node {
    stage("Fetch Uploaded File") {
        sh '''
        ls -l file1.zip file2.zip
        ls -l ${WORKSPACE}/file1.zip ${WORKSPACE}/file2.zip
        '''
     }


}
```

Tried with def input file option per other post, but no luck of reaching uploaded file. Any inputs?

```
    def inputFile = input message: 'Upload file', parameters: [file(name: 'data.ear')]
    new hudson.FilePath(new File("$workspace/data.ear")).copyFrom(inputFile)
    inputFile.delete()
```

With scripted full pipeline pasted above, getting below error..

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Fetch Uploaded File)
[Pipeline] sh
[testSh] Running shell script
+ ls -l file1.zip file2.zip
ls: cannot access file1.zip: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access file2.zip: No such file or directory
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 2
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Here is another failure attempt of trying it differently

`node {
    stage("Upload File") {
        
        def inputFile = input message: 'Upload file', parameters: [file(name: 'data.zip')]
        new hudson.FilePath(new File("$WORKSPACE/data.zip")).copyFrom(inputFile)
        inputFile.delete()

        sh '''
        ls -l data.zip
        ls -l ${WORKSPACE}/data.zip 
        '''
     }
}`

Comment: And corresponding error being..

`[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Upload File)
[Pipeline] input
Input requested
Approved by admin
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use new java.io.File java.lang.String
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectNew(StaticWhitelist.java:187)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onNewInstance`

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug [JENKINS-27413](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27413).

There is however a library with a workaround that can help you https://github.com/janvrany/jenkinsci-unstashParam-library. As described in the readme you can add this library to your Jenkins ([Extending with Shared Libraries](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/)) and use it the following way:

```
library "jenkinsci-unstashParam-library"
node {
   def file_in_workspace = unstashParam "file"
   sh "cat ${file_in_workspace}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Vitalii Vitrenko

As it's binary, looked at slight variation as per here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57464227/upload-file-in-jenkins-input-step-to-workspace & is working now!

Comment: Actually neither answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57464227/upload-file-in-jenkins-input-step-to-workspace post is working not the solution which you pointed @Vitalii Vitrenko

With other post it results in 'Can not open file '' as archive ' error

and with solution which you pointed yields to following error : 'ERROR: unstashParam: No file parameter named 'file''

Comment: And to add, its binary file which I am looking to upload relatively huge, which is failing using either of approach